# How to dump variables as MATLAB source code?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to dump a MATLAB variable as the source code for the corresponding literal initializer?  IOW, I'm looking for some function `x` such that, for example:

```
>> A = zeros(2);
>> x(A)
ans =
[0 0; 0 0]
>> class(x(A))
ans =
char
```

Is there such a function, or an easy way to achieve the same effect?  (I realize that literal initializers may not exist for some MATLAB items; for such items the problem is intrinsically unsolvable.)

I am aware of the fact that MATLAB offers many ways to save data to files, but none of the ways I've found produce MATLAB *source code*, which is what I'm after.

Comment: There seem to be a few scripts on the MATLAB file exchange which seem to do this. Have you tried them out yet? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24447-generate-m-file-code-for-any-matlab-variable and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24447-generate-m-file-code-for-any-matlab-variable/content/examples/html/gencode_example.html

Comment: @TajMorton: not yet; thanks for the tip!

Comment: The answers you have already seem to work well, bust just FYI, the latest version of MATLAB (2014a) contains new functionality ([matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.savevariablestoscript.html)) to do exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple numeric values (and also char arrays), the `mat2str` function does what you're looking for.

For example, (from the MATLAB documentation):

> Consider the matrix
>
> ```
> x = [3.85 2.91; 7.74 8.99]
> x =
>     3.8500    2.9100
>     7.7400    8.9900
> ```
>
> The statement
>
> ```
> A = mat2str(x)
> ```
>
> produces
>
> ```
> A =
>     [3.85 2.91;7.74 8.99]
> ```
>
> where `A` is a string of 21 characters, including the square brackets, spaces, and a semicolon.

Further, passing the string `'class'` as the second argument ensure that the answer will be case to the correct numeric type.

See [the MATLAB documentation for `mat2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html), or run

```
doc mat2str
```

in MATLAB, for more information.

Comment: Nice function, thanks for the tip! Do you know of a built-in way to do this for non-numeric types like a cell array (`C = {'one';'two';'three'}` doesn't work)? Even the variable editor won't  directly save to a .m file for a cell, but a copy/paste from the editor gives code.

Comment: Assuming each member of the cell is itself of a type supported by `mat2str`, you can do `Cs = cellfun(@mat2str,C,'UniformOutput','false')'; pattern = strrep(mat2str(nan(size(C)),'NaN','%s'); A = sprintf(['{' pattern(2:end-1) '}'], Cs{:});`

Answer (score 2):

I know you are looking for a *function* that can do this, rather than an interactive procedure, but for anyone else who wants to do this manually...

The MATLAB variable editor/viewer has built-in code generation functionality. Open the variable in the editor, click the save icon, and choose MATLAB Script (*.m) file type (default is .mat):

[image]

The resulting MatrixCode.m:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Generated by MATLAB on 3-Mar-2014 17:35:49
%  MATLAB version: 8.3.0.73043 (R2014a)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------


M = ...
  [16 2 3 13;
   5 11 10 8;
   9 7 6 12;
   4 14 15 1];
```

Maybe someone with Java and reverse engineering skills can figure out how to call this GUI operation from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

As [Sam Roberts commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134958/how-to-dump-variables-as-matlab-source-code/70007902#comment33876114_22134958), [`matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.savevariablestoscript.html) is now the ultimate method to convert *any* datatype to a script. This method was introduced in 2014a and works for `struct`, `cell`, and all primitive datatypes.

chappjc's method is also correct, but it uses a MATLAB GUI frontend to the [`saveVariablesToScript`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.savevariablestoscript.html) method.